# Get the dynamoDB's primary key list

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I would like to extract the primary key of table to a list , but find no api to do that.

for example, as the [amazon example thread table](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/SampleTablesAndData.html#ThreadBySubjectTableSchemaAndData), I want to ask how to :

1) get the `hash primary key` list, in the [amazon example thread table](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/SampleTablesAndData.html#ThreadBySubjectTableSchemaAndData) it would be an array of ["Amazon DynamoDB", "Amazon S3"]

2) with assigning the `hash primary key` to "Amazon DynamoDB", I want to get the `range primary key` list and it would be an array of ["Amazon DynamoDB Thread 1", "Amazon DynamoDB Thread 2"]

Answer (score 4):

For 1 what you want is to run a `Scan` operation on a table. `Scan` Gets all the items of the list. Depends on the API you are using, you can get only the hash key or any attributes you want.

For 2 what you want is `Query` - which gets a hash attribute and returns all rows that have the hash attribute (can be more than one).

Overview - [Query and Scan operations](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/QueryAndScan.html)

Java mapper reference - [Scan](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/DynamoDBMapper.html#scan%28java.lang.Class,%20com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBScanExpression%29) and [Query](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/DynamoDBMapper.html#query%28java.lang.Class,%20com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBQueryExpression%29)

Comment: When use `scan` for 1), it means I have to spend a lot of read capacity units to get all items then extract the result of just two `hash primary key`? wow ~ it's very expensive! any other choice?

Comment: You can choose which attributes to fetch - meaning that your read throuout won't go crazy if you have big attributes for each item. You can also add conditions to minimize returned results which reduces network IO but doesn't save throughout

Comment: it's useful info for me, but I found no description on AWS about the spent read capacity unit of scan depending on the attributes retrieved (it has a similar description on query but not for scan). any reference to prompt? thanks a lot

Comment: I would write a post on the AWS DynamoDB forum asking for documentation clarifications.

Comment: Could I expect that if I just want the `scan` to return `hash primary key` and no any other attributes then each return item size should be smaller than 100 byte. And I need only single read capacity unit for more than 40 items?

Comment: I can't say for sure. You could benchmark it and watch the cloudwatch data to see if you got throttled

Comment: I know this is old, but I ended up here, so for anyone else:
The Scan operation uses capacity based on what it scans not what it returns. This means that no matter what filters you apply, or what limited attributes you return, you will use the same read capacity, and that read capacity will take in to account the FULL size of every object it scans. Here's an applicable link to the docs: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Scan.html#Scan.CapacityUnits